# WHERE clause causing error in qsqlquery. Query works without WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, qtsql

I am working on a project in which I take data from the input fields and update the data in the data base based on the serial no.
Here is my code:

```
QSqlQuery sqry;
if(sqry.prepare("UPDATE second_weight "
                "SET s_weight_type=:s_weight_type, s_weight=:s_weight, s_driver_included=:s_driver_included,s_amount=:s_amount,"
                "s_paid_status=:s_paid_status, sdate=:sdate, stime=:stime"
                "WHERE first_weight_FK = :s_sID")){
    sqry.bindValue(":s_weight_type",weightstrSec);
    sqry.bindValue(":s_weight",weightSec);
    sqry.bindValue(":s_driver_included",dIncStrSec);
    sqry.bindValue(":s_amount",amntSec);
    sqry.bindValue(":s_paid_status", statusSec);
    sqry.bindValue(":s_sdate",datevalSec);
    sqry.bindValue(":s_stime",timevalSec);
    sqry.bindValue(":s_sID",srStrSec);
    sqry.exec();
```

I have tried running this query without WHERE clause and it works that way. But when I use WHERE clause following error is generated.

```
QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Pa_RaM006 first_weight_FK = Pa_RaM007'."
```

I am working with MS ACCESS database file. Can Anyone help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: I don’t see sID in bindvalue, which is a condition in `WHERE first_weight_FK = :sID")` clause

Comment: Thanks for reply. It was an typo it still does not work.

Comment: You’re missing a space before WHERE? Always print out the exact string you have to see what it contains.